# How to load random overlay items in google maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

My question for today is that i want a functionality like this. I am having latitude and longitude retrieved from webservice like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<root>
<login>
<all_events>
<status>True</status> 
<message>success</message> 
<event1>
<latitude>12.9775</latitude> 
<longitude>77.5861</longitude> 
</event1>
<event2>
<latitude>12.9739</latitude> 
<longitude>77.5946</longitude> 
</event2>
<event3>
<latitude>13.0251</latitude> 
<longitude>77.3364</longitude> 
</event3>
<event4>
<latitude>13.142836343350103</latitude> 
<longitude>78.09993109375</longitude> 
</event4>
<event5>
<latitude>12.966246955941406</latitude> 
<longitude>77.74836859375</longitude> 
</event5>
<event6>
<latitude>12.896646920163738</latitude> 
<longitude>77.319901796875</longitude> 
</event6>
<event7>
<latitude>13.239104403448842</latitude> 
<longitude>78.066972109375</longitude> 
</event7>
</all_events>
</login>
</root>
```

How to create an overlay item for each of these points ie. an overlay item corresponding to latitude and longitude?
Please help me out.

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: @Maneesh: i know how to create an overlay item. I want to knw how to save these xml data into an array list and load from the arraylist to display as these markers!

Comment: @Maneesh: I want seperate markers for each of these events listed above!

Comment: First parse the xml using http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/. Then add it to Arraylist.  Then iterate through arraylist using for loop and then add indivudual GeoCode using the developer.android tutorial

Comment: you can set different drawable for separate marker as ...Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

Comment: @Maneesh. Do you have any samples implementing my functionality?